# Hashicorp Nomad and Consul API - Get all services addresses

Tags: api, rest, consul, nomad

I'm building a self-configured proxy for my Nomad cluster. For that, I need to retrieve all jobs running in the cluster, and their allocated IP's and port's for every container running. This way I can autogenerate the reverse proxy configuration, and a load balancer.
I have to get this either through Nomad's or Consul's API, but I need to do get it in just one API call. I know I can get all services in a given node, by calling Consul's endpoint `/v1/catalog/node/nomad-node-3`, but I have to specify the node.
Is there any endpoint that I can use for this?

Comment: Wouldn't a proxy be per service? A service runs over multiple nodes, so you shouldn't be using the Node API endpoint... Instead, seems you want the service catalog. Otherwise, Fabio or Traefik work based on Consul tagging

Comment: Not quite. The proxy holds the up-to-date catalog of all services and their upstreams, then aplies some load balancing to requests. I managed to accomplish it with some some lua code. The proxy scans all consul nodes every few seconds to keep the list of services and upstreams up-to-date. It's not the best solution, but it works for my use case. I'll add a proper answer to this post soon, including the code I've used.

Comment: Have you considered using consul-template to generate the configs for your reverse proxy, or using Consul's [blocking queries](https://www.consul.io/api/features/blocking) to eliminate the periodic polling of nodes, and extra server load that comes along with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that does that for the Fabio load balancer: https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio/blob/15565deb06bf2ef7a8b67f42e958c7b370bf29da/registry/consul/service.go

You’ll notice [here](https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio/blob/15565deb06bf2ef7a8b67f42e958c7b370bf29da/registry/consul/service.go#L43) that Fabio doesn’t actually query for all services that are running, just health checks that are passing. I think this makes sense, and you might want to use this strategy, since you might not want to direct traffic to services that are unhealthy. On the other hand this means fabio has no visibility into services that are failing their health checks but potentially should be routable.

That call will get you the services that are passing, after that fabio queries for the [service tags here](https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio/blob/15565deb06bf2ef7a8b67f42e958c7b370bf29da/registry/consul/service.go#L114). This is where nomad puts the metadata about where those services can be found (ip/port etc).

Not sure if this can all be done in a single request, since the [list services](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/catalog#list-services) endpoint doesn’t contain the tag metadata that you need.

---

Additional details in response to comment:

This code uses a wait index and consul's [concept of watches](https://www.consul.io/docs/dynamic-app-config/watches). You can see that configured [here](https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio/blob/15565deb06bf2ef7a8b67f42e958c7b370bf29da/registry/consul/service.go#L37-L43). So there is still a very minor delay, but this request is not constant polling. It makes an outbound request to consul and hangs until consul has new changes to report. In practice this is very quick and has not led to latency issues for me (although they still technically exist, network request overhead, re-querying for tags, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nice to see how others do it!
Actually, from my code, by querying consul's endpoint I'm making sure I get only healthy upstreams (I assume all my services must be in a healthy state). The issue with this approach is, given there is an implied delay because of the polling mechanism, it could happen that an upstream goes unhealthy, but my proxy still thinks it's not (because it hasn't done next poll yet), and routes requests to it. But for now, this is good enough for my use case.

Comment: Hey @Cristian added more comments above. There isn't a typical polling interval, the requests wait for changes before responding. 

Please also accept the answer if it answers your question :)